# Use if statement to get percentage of input?

Tags: javascript, html

Everything runs correctly, but I want to add a few things. At the very end of the function I want to change the height of the canvas by comparing how many you got correct out of the amount that you wanted to answer, but with a percentage. Sorry if this is difficult to understand.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {

score = 0;

questionAmount = prompt('How many question would you like to solve?');

for(i = 0; i < questionAmount; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);

    question = prompt('What is ' + x + ' * ' + y + ' = ?');

    if(question == null || isNaN(question)) {
        break;
    }
    if(question == x * y) {
        score++;
    }
}

alert('You got ' + score + ' out of ' + questionAmount + ' correct.');
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="content"></canvas>
<br />
<button onclick="myFunction()">CLICK</button>
```

Comment: So you want some bar that is bigger when the user has more questions correct? [Something like this?](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/GetFile.aspx?Page=jquery_ui_mvc_progressbar&File=basic.PNG)

Comment: What is the problem you have faced?

Comment: And yes kevin, the example is very similar to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the percentage and apply it:

```
var correctPercent = (parseDouble(score) / parseDouble(questionAmount)) * 100;

//change the target elements style, apply above variable
document.getElementById("content").style.height = correctPercent + "%";
```

Comment: That doesn't produce a percentage value, it's just a fraction? Btw, at least `score` doesn't need to be parsed

Comment: Edited @Bergi -- was getting there

Comment: @Bergi mul by 100 to get to a proper percentage, but the math is correct